# Node.js, API, ispmanager, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, mariadb

I am using ispmanager to make an API for personal usage, in my computer works fine, but when making it online, and using npm start in the bash of ispmanager he returns:

```
bash-4.2$ npm start                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                   
> cosmisexodus@1.0.0 start                                                                                                         
> node server.js                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                   
Servidor ativo na porta 3000.                                                                                                      
Database connection error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306                                                              
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16)                                                              
    --------------------                                                                                                           
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/cosmicexodus/data/www/api.cosmicexodus.xyz/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/var/www/cosmicexodus/data/www/api.cosmicexodus.xyz/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/var/www/cosmicexodus/data/www/api.cosmicexodus.xyz/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/cosmicexodus/data/www/api.cosmicexodus.xyz/app/models/db.js:13:12)                             
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)                                                                  
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)                                                    
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)                                                                      
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)                                                             
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)                                                                   
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18) {                                                                        
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}                                                                                                                                  
/var/www/cosmicexodus/data/www/api.cosmicexodus.xyz/app/models/db.js:16                                                            
    throw error; // You can choose to throw the error or handle it as needed                                                       
    ^                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                   
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306                                                                                         
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16)                                                              
    --------------------                                                                                                           
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/cosmicexodus/data/www/api.cosmicexodus.xyz/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/var/www/cosmicexodus/data/www/api.cosmicexodus.xyz/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/var/www/cosmicexodus/data/www/api.cosmicexodus.xyz/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/cosmicexodus/data/www/api.cosmicexodus.xyz/app/models/db.js:13:12)                             
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)                                                                  
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)                                                    
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)                                                                      
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)                                                             
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)                                                                   
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18) {                                                                        
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

My `db.config.js` looks correct:

```
module.exports = {
    DBSERVER: 'localhost', ispmanager recomends using localhost, butI have used 127.0.0.1
    DBUSER: 'admin', 
    DBPASS: 'password', 
    DBNAME: 'test',
    PORT: 3306,
  };
```

And this is my `db.js`:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const DBConfig = require('../config/db.config.js');

// Criar conexão à base de dados
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: DBConfig.DBSERVER,
  user: DBConfig.DBUSER,
  password: DBConfig.DBPASS,
  database: DBConfig.DBNAME
});

// Open conection to database
connection.connect(error => {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Database connection error:', error); // Log the error details
    throw error; // You can choose to throw the error or handle it as needed
  } else {
    console.log('Connection to the database established');
  }
});

module.exports = connection;
```

My `server.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const corsOptions = {
   origin: 'http://localhost'
 };
 //app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// tratamento (parse) de pedidos de content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());

// tratamento (parse) de pedidos de content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// route de "entrada" - apenas para efeito de teste
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "CosmicExodus . mind" });
});

// importação das rotas com um argumento de inicialização
require('./app/routes/exodus.routes.js')(app);

// ativação do servidor, onde serão recebidos os pedidos, na porta definida
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor ativo na porta ${PORT}.`);
});
```

When using bash I can connect to the database and retrieve data, but then trying to start the server I always get that. MySQL is working.

Tried solutions found In other posts:

- Changed from localHost to 127.0.0.1 and vice-versa;
- Added port 3306 to db.js and db.config.js;
- Checked if all values login are correct;
- Checkef if mysql service is online (it is);
- Changed host to socketPath: '/path/to/mysql.sock';
- Tried diferent ports instead of 3306, like 80;
- Its running on a server, no xamp related;
- Checked the configuration for my ispmanager(localhost and port 3306);
- Have tried other things also, don´t remember exatly what.

Comment: Your error message shows a tcp connection. When testing from the shell did you use tcp or socket. `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uadmin -p` will connect via tcp and you can confirm by typing `\s` once connected in mysql client. You should see - `Connection: localhost via TCP/IP`.

Comment: I am getting: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) , it means i am using socket? And if so, how can I change to tcp?

Comment: What OS and how was MySQL installed? Try using grep to see if [skip-networking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_skip_networking) is enabled - `sudo grep -r 'skip' /etc/mysql`. Alternatively, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'skip_net%';` when connected to MySQL.

Comment: Its an online server called ispmanager, I guess its mysql and maria db, it appers bash4.2 on the input shell, so I dont know wich os the server is using.

Comment: I mean I am using windows for local tests, but since I am trying to use the server to make it online, does not matter the OS i am using in my machine. I am using this to host the node.js server.
https://www.ispmanager.com/docs

Comment: /etc/mysql is not a file show is not a command.

Comment: When i use this: mysql -h localhost -u <username> -p, 
I can conect to the database:
```
bash-4.2$ mysql -h localhost -u admin -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.                                                                        
Your MariaDB connection id is *****
Server version: 5.5.68-MariaDB MariaDB Server
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.        
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: I changed to a diferent socketPath and did not fixed the issue, but at least conects to the dataBase now. So thanks a lot for your feedback.

Comment: Is mysqld listening - `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep mysqld`? Check os/version with `cat /etc/os-release`. That is a [very old version](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-5568-release-notes/) of [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes/). ISPmanager installs both native and Docker based MariaDB instances, so it is hard to tell what is going on without being able to see exactly what is running where. [Docs](https://www.ispmanager.com/docs/ispmanager/alternative-mysql-versions#technology): If you create a MariaDB instance and call it `mymariadb`, it maps a volume to `/var/lib/mymariadb`.

Comment: I know what you mean, they marked this post as duplicate, even tho is not, you were right, the serve worked based on socket and I was using tcp protocol, adding the socketPath to the server.js solved the problem. Thanksss